# Why is an empty comment (just "//") added above the Index action of a new controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I add a new controller in Visual Studio, it creates code as follows:

```
public class RatesController : Controller
{
    //     <-- Why is this empty comment added?
    // GET: /Rates/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm just curious about the reason.

Comment: The dull answer is "because that's what's in the template". Unless the author shows up, you're unlikely to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't serve a purpose - it's just a particular style that someone has used. When you Add a controller in Visual Studio, a text template (Controller.tt, under `%VisualStudioInstallLocation%\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddController`) is invoked. This template starts as:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = (MvcTextTemplateHost)(Host);
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace <#= mvcHost.Namespace #>
{
    public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: <#= (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.AreaName)) ? ("/" + mvcHost.AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#= mvcHost.ControllerRootName #>/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

<#
if(mvcHost.AddActionMethods) {
#>
        //
        // GET: <#= (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.AreaName)) ? ("/" + mvcHost.AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#= mvcHost.ControllerRootName #>/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: <#= (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.AreaName)) ? ("/" + mvcHost.AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#= mvcHost.ControllerRootName #>/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

As you can see, the empty `//`s are consistent across all methods, and nothing will ever be placed on those lines. If it truly is a concern to you, you could edit the template to remove these lines (I'd recommend taking a backup first)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the author of the template desired to underline that that action method is supposed to be used mainly by the `GET` method of the Rates Controller (rather than by vs POST, DELETE or other methods).

Here is an other example template (ApiController.tt). Remark the GET, POST and DELETE comments before actions:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = (MvcTextTemplateHost)(Host);
string pathFragment = mvcHost.ControllerRootName.ToLowerInvariant();
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace <#= mvcHost.Namespace #>
{
    public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : ApiController
    {
<#
if(mvcHost.AddActionMethods) {
#>
        // GET api/<#= pathFragment #>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<#= pathFragment #>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<#= pathFragment #>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<#= pathFragment #>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<#= pathFragment #>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
<#
}
#>
    }
}
```